Why does the partition function method introduce a $\frac{1} { }$ term while calculating entropy for a classical gas?
I am trying to calculate the entropy for a classical two dimensional free gas of  particles in a box of side  and total energy . Using two methods, I obtain different scaling factors inside the logarithm of the number of microstates:
Microcanonical Method (Direct Counting):
Here, I compute the phase space volume directly with the energy constraint . The number of microstates is given by:
$$ \Omega=\frac{1}{N!}\left(\frac{1}{h^2}L^2\int_{0}^{\infty}d^2p\right)^N=\frac{1}{N!}(L^2E)^N .$$
Here I kept $\frac{2\pi m}{h^2}=1$. To get the entropy, we use Boltzman Law followed by Stirling approximation and get $$S=K\ln\left(\frac{1}{N!} (L^2 E)^N\right)=Nk\ln\left(L^2E\right)-Nk\ln N +Nk\tag{1}$$
Canonical Partition Function Method:
Here, I calculate the partition function at a fixed temperature  as $$ Z=\frac{1}{N!}\left(\frac{2\pi m kT}{h^2}\right)^N$$ where T is related to the energy  via $=\frac{}{k}$. Substituting this into the partition function yields$$Z=\frac{1}{N!}\left[\frac{L^2 E}{N}\right]^N$$
In short taking negative KT times natural log and then differentiating with respect to temperature with a minus sign we get entropy $$S =Nk\ln\left(\frac{L^2E}{N}\right)-Nk\ln N +Nk\tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2), we can see there is a difference in the solutions. Latter contains $\frac{1}{N}$, and the former doesn't contain. Can you help me understand why there is a difference and which one is more precise?

$log(a/b)=log(a)-log(b)$ and $N\gg 1$

@RogerV. I had this question in an exam and both options i provided were present there.So which 1 is more precise?

Classically, entropy is defined up to an additive constant, so the question seems a bit weird to me... but also your first expression does not seem correct - shouldn't the power be $N-1$? There might be also additional factorial factor.

@RogerV. Why should the power be N-1?i calculate the phase volume which is given by $\Omega = \frac{1}{N! h^{2N}} \int d^{2N}q , d^{2N}p$

Perhaps... I calculate it differently... but then I probably also get a different answer for the canonical. You will have to retrace both calculations using the same method - canonical is derived from microcanonical by integrating thermostat... or perhaps, again, it is me who does it this way.

@RogerV. I m thankful to people like you.i just edited my previous comment.you can check whether my expression is correct.

I calculate it as $\int d^{2N}p\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{p_i^2}{2m}-E\right)$ - I admit that this is a peculiar way, rare in textbooks... but in your expression the constraint is missing.

@RogerV. I was about to write it before you as i knew i am missing the constraint but the text books often use the approach of multiplying individual states like if they were independent which they are not.i am not sure if they do it in Case of no. Of microstates by taking $$ \Omega = \frac{1}{N!}\left(\frac{1}{h^2} \int d^{2}q d^{2}p\right)^N $$ as $$\Omega = \frac{1}{N!}\frac{1}{h^{2N}}\int d^{2N}q  d^{2N}p$$ But i m sure they do it in case of partition functions as $Z_n$ (partition function of N particles) $=\frac{1}{N!}Z^n$ where Z is the single particle partition function.

Partition functions factorize because they have this special property. The number of states does not factorize, as @RogerV. said, we have an additional constraint, and it not factorize. The reason is well explained in this answer
